# Rendering JSON in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I used "mix phoenix.gen.json" to generate the code for rendering json resulting in view below:

```
defmodule Pghm.SightingsView do    
  use Pghm.Web, :view

  def render("sighting.json", %{sighting: sighting}) do
    %{what: sighting.what,
      lat:  sighting.lat,
      long: sighting.long}
  end

  def render("index.json", %{sightings: sightings}) do
    %{data: render_many(sightings, Pghm.SightingsView, "sighting.json")}
  end

  def render("show.json", %{sighting: sighting}) do
    %{data: render_one(sighting, Pghm.SightingsView, "sighting.json")}
  end
end
```

However when I attempt to access call it I receive: Could not render "sighting.json" for Pghm.SightingsView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "web/templates/sightings". No templates were compiled for this module.
Assigns:

Everywhere I've looked indicates that this should work, but I get no love.

Comment: Are you able to show us the controller action that gets called as well please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I started with Phoenix recently too, but probably I know what's the problem.

```
def render("sighting.json", %{sighting: sighting}) do
  %{what: sighting.what,
    lat:  sighting.lat,
    long: sighting.long}
end
```

The definition of this function says, that it will work only if you call it this way:

```
render("sighting.json", %{sighting: some_data})
```

But this code:

```
%{data: render_many(sightings, Pghm.SightingsView, "sighting.json")}
```

Passes a sightings itself to render's second parameter, not the required %{sighting: sighting} thing. So Elixir couldn't find a render implementation that suits given parameters and raises the error.

Changing

```
def render("sighting.json", %{sighting: sighting}) do
```

to just

```
def render("sighting.json", sighting) do
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I've had exactly this problem today, and it was because I pluralised the view's name, like in Rails.

According to comments in the Phoenix source (1), the key is inferred from the view name.

> A collection is any enumerable of structs. This function   returns
>   the rendered collection in a list:
>         `render_many users, UserView, "show.html"`
>    is roughly equivalent to:

```
Enum.map(users, fn user ->
  render(UserView, "show.html", user: user)
end)
```

> The underlying user is passed to the view and template as `:user`,   which is inferred from the view name. The name of the key in assigns can be customized with the `:as` option

(1) https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/8a6beef9e13f049a8458db25b71fb70afae7673a/lib/phoenix/view.ex#L267

**So try this :**

```
defmodule Pghm.SightingView do    
  use Pghm.Web, :view

  def render("sighting.json", %{sighting: sighting}) do
    %{what: sighting.what,
      lat:  sighting.lat,
      long: sighting.long}
  end

  def render("index.json", %{sightings: sightings}) do
    %{data: render_many(sightings, Pghm.SightingView, "sighting.json")}
  end

  def render("show.json", %{sighting: sighting}) do
    %{data: render_one(sighting, Pghm.SightingView, "sighting.json")}
  end
end
```

Comment: Another solution (as noted in the documentation) would be adding `as: :sighting` as the 4th parameter when using `render_many/4` function.

Comment: @DapengLi that solved my problem! the missing link is adding `:as` option